# Cite Master's Thesis using natbib

Tags: citing, natbib

I'm currently writing my Bachelor's thesis and I want to cite a Master's thesis. I have some issues and I'm really new to Latex why I do not know how to help myself. As you always want a code example, here you go:

```
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\begin{document}
\input{content/01_introduction.tex} 
\newpage
\bibliography{bib/bibliography.bib}
\end{document}
```

And my bibliography.bib file looks like this:

```
@book{Barsoukov2005,
    author = {Barsoukov, Evgenij and Dr. J. Ross Macdonald},
    year = {2005},
    title = {Impedance Spectroscopy: Theory, Experiment, and Applications},
    publisher = {{John Wiley & Sons, Inc.}},
    isbn = {978-0-471-64749-2},
    doi = {10.1002/0471716243}
}
@article{Loeffler1987,
    author = {Loeffler, K. U. and Lee, W. R.},
    title = {Argyrosis of the lacrimal sac.},
    journal = {Graefes Arch Clin Exp Ophthalmol.},
    volume = {255},
    number = {2},
    pages = {146--150},
    year = {1987}
}
```

And in my text, when I cite, it looks like this

```
blabla blablbla \cite{Loeffler1987}. blablalblalba \cite{Loeffler1987,Barsoukov2005}
```

My problem is now with the Master's thesis. I tried '@mastersthesis' and '@masterthesis'. But both does not work and also "deletes" all the references above... Very strange. Can you help me see what's wrong?

Regards, Ximi

EDIT: I tried it with and without **s**

```
@mastersthesis{Plum2007,
    author = {Plum, M. A.},
    title = {{Orientierungsspezifische Studie der
        Cytochrom-c-Oxidase in einer biomimetischen
        Architektur auf Metalloberfl{\"{a}chen}},
    school = {Johannes Gutenberg Universit{\"{a}t Mainz},
    year = {2007}
}
```

Comment: can you post how you formatted your @MastersThesis entry?

Comment: @MarcoLübbecke, done :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for the example. The entry is syntactically incorrect, too few closing (or too many opening) braces in the title and also in the school (the confusion probably came from the umlauts). For me it works once these issues are removed with

```
@mastersthesis{Plum2007,
    author = {Plum, M. A.},
    title = {{Orientierungsspezifische Studie der
        Cytochrom-c-Oxidase in einer biomimetischen
        Architektur auf Metalloberfl{\"{a}chen}}},
    school = {Johannes Gutenberg Universit\"{a}t Mainz},
    year = {2007}
}
```

Note that the braces `{` and `}` can have different roles, for delimiting an entry (for that you can also use double quotes `"`), or for embracing a LaTeX command like in `L\"{u}bbecke`. You will also use the braces if you wish to keep the entry "as is" eg. with respect to capitalization. If you do not use the braces, `bibtex` would turn your entry into ... architektur ... instead of Architektur, because without your help (with braces) it does not know about German capitalization.

Comment: ok wow, now I feel a little stupid ;) Thank you very much! I was looking for a problem with the citation type. I didn't check the braces... It works perfectly fine now!